# writing null to DataOutput in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using Hadoop 0.20.2. I am writing an object `X` which implements `Writable`.

`X` has several fields which are instances of `Integer`. For these fields, the `null` value has a special significance.

When serializing the object, by writing to `DataOutput out` in the `write` method of the `Writable` interface, is there a way I can write `null`? Or should I use separate booleans which indicates the value is null?

Comment: Did you try writing *null* as it is? can you share your overridden *write* method?

Comment: Try writing a test where you construct an X with null values, serialize it, deserialize it and confirm the values are what you expect them to be.  If that works then it should work under hadoop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Booleans are the standard procedure for flagging object propertys as `NULL`.

Consider this case:

```
public class LongMessage implements Writable {

  private long tag;
  private String data;
  // interface methods omitted first
}
```

So `data` might be `null`, for whatever reasons. So I would implement read/write as follows:

```
  @Override
  public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    tag = in.readLong();
    if (in.readBoolean()) {
      data = in.readUTF();
    } else {
      data = null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
    out.writeLong(tag);
    if (data != null) {
      out.writeBoolean(true);
      out.writeUTF(data);
    } else {
      out.writeBoolean(false);
    }
  }
```

It is even pretty readable. But note that you have constant overhead of one byte per record as stated in the JavaDocs of `#writeBoolean`:

> Writes a boolean value to this output stream. If the argument v is
>   true, the value (byte)1 is written; if v is false, the value (byte)0
>   is written

Comment: I'm not sure, but if I remember correctly Hadoop reuses Writable instances, which means you should set data back to default value if you read a boolean false from the DataInput. Otherwise you might end up with a value from another run.

Comment: @whiskeysierra exactly. Added an else statement setting data to null.

Answer (score 1):

NullWritable is a special type of Writable, as it has a zero-length serialization. No bytes
are written to, or read from, the stream. 
for further reference look at hadoop definitive guide pg:104

Answer (score 0):

When serializing, the size of a **null** object is exactly 1 byte in the [Java object serialization protocol](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/serialization/spec/protocol.html). So I don't think you would have any issue in the `write` method of your custom `Writable`.

As a general rule, it really depends what you're trying to model. If you're trying to represent a `Boolean` and **null** means it's not here, you should probably default to false. If it's an integer, you should default to whatever the default value is for your dataset. So unless there's some specific processing associated with the "special significance" you're mentioning, I think you're fine with writing a **null**, otherwise you should use a default value.